# How to have dynamic selector with DefaultMessageListenerContainer (in spring-boot)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have a spring-boot application with ActiveMQ JMS. I have a queue in the application which will get messages with a string property say color. Value of color can be red, green or blue. Application has a Rest service where it will get list of color(s) { one or more } which should be used as a SELECTOR when listening for the messages on the queue. Over the lifetime of the application, this might change, so the value of SELECTOR can look like
**"color='red'"**, **"color='blue' OR color='red'"**  or **"color='green'"**.

```
@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter adapter() {        
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(new Object() {
        // message handler
    });
}
@Bean
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf) throws Exception {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer c = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    c.setMessageListener(adapter());
    c.setConcurrency(this.concurrency);
    c.setMessageSelector(this.selector);
    c.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    c.setDestinationName(this.q);

    return c;
}
```

Was planning to use above code to achieve this; code works fine to start with initial selector, however when selector needs to change following code does not work.

```
c.stop();
// modify value of selector
c.setMessageSelector(this.selector);
c.start();
```

Looks like, I have a working solution. I put **@Scope("prototype")** on top of method container() and have a method which instantiates a new DefaultMessageListenerContainer whenever selector changes.

```
public void xx(String selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer c = 
        context.getBean("container", DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
    c.start();
}
```

Is this the right way to go about this? Also, when selector changes and I instantiate a new DefaultMessageListenerContainer, what's the correct way to shutdown/stop existing DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

regards,
Yogi

Answer (score 1):

The prototype thing looks a very bad idea to me.

`MessageListenerContainer` is meant to be a singleton that is responsible to handle listeners for a particular queue or topic configuration. The selector is a JMS spec so you basically need to reconfigure the listener container at runtime which will require you to fully stop the listener, change its configuration and restart it. I haven't seen your code but I  don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Having said that, why are you using a selector for this? If the selector changes during the lifetime of your application, wouldn't it be better to actually perform that selection in your own logic? Having a selector at the JMS level is interesting if you have several message types on the same queue and you want different thread pools for them (i.e. you want 5 concurrent listeners for "red" and only 2 for green for instance). If you don't have that requirement having a generic route that filters the incoming message is probably a better idea.

If you do have that requirement, stopping the container, changing its config and restarting it should work. Unfortunately it doesn't so I've created [SPR-14604](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14604) to track this issue.

Comment: Thanks @stephane-nicoll for your reply. 1> I have created a test project in bitbucket, here is the link https://bitbucket.org/yovyom/jmsdemo/  changeSelector method of class JmsListener changes the selector and it doesn't take any effect. README file explains how to test/use the application. 2> About your comment about doing selection in own logic: Idea is to distribute load across listeners based on SELECTOR. some listeners won't be capable of processing a message with say color='red' and we don't want to create queues dynamically, each corresponding to a color.

Comment: Hello  @stephane-nicoll , did you get a chance to take a look at the spring-boot project  https://bitbucket.org/yovyom/jmsdemo

Comment: I had a look and there is something fishy indeed. I've created an issue myself on the tracker to look into it. I still thinks that you shouldn't use selector for this. How about a listener on your queue + a filter in code? (you can get the header in your own code and invoke one bean or another depending on the selector ...).

Comment: Thanks @stephane-nicoll. Will consider other approaches.